# parse_date_time fails to process strings from file

Tags: r

I cannot get simple strings in a file processed by parse_date_time, running Rstudio under Windows 7. Here is an example:

```
t<-read.csv("test3.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# show data
print(t)
                 Date
1 2014-03-15 01:02:16
2 2014-03-15 01:06:26
3 2014-03-15 01:09:16

summary(t)
 Date          
 Length:3          
 Class :character  
 Mode  :character 



parse_date_time(t, "%Y%m%d %H%M%S")
#[1] NA

Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

At the same time, quoting the string from the file works as it is supposed to:

```
parse_date_time("2014-03-15 01:02:16", "%Y%m%d %H%M%S")
#[1] "2014-03-15 01:02:16 UTC"
```

What could I be doing wrong here? Please help!

Thanks - Zoli

Comment: Please provide complete self contained questions.   If you use commands not part of R then provide the appropriate library calls.

Answer (score 0):

Because `t` is a `data.frame`, the vector to be parsed must be inputted instead.

```
library(lubridate)
parse_date_time(t$Date, "%Y%m%d %H%M%S")
#[1] "2014-03-15 01:02:16 UTC" "2014-03-15 01:06:26 UTC"
#[3] "2014-03-15 01:09:16 UTC"
```

**Data**

```
t <- structure(list(Date = c("2014-03-15 01:02:16", "2014-03-15 01:06:26", 
"2014-03-15 01:09:16")), .Names = "Date", row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = "data.frame")
```